# Access simultaneous network (CCTV, Wi-Fi) on single config

Tags: routing, router, ip

Suppose you have a DVR configured to a bridge, by connecting my computer to this bridge I can access the DVR menu/cameras as intended.

When the bridge is connected to a proper router (that is in turn connected to a WIRED internet/ethernet connection) all works as intended.. ie. any computer that connects to the ROUTER can now access both the DVR menu/cameras (from the configured local IP) AND the Internet as normal.

**Q.** Suppose there is NO wired internet available. The connection comes from standalone mobile hotspots. What is the proper set-up/config to allow a PC to connect to a single device to access both the DVR IP and the Internet?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be unclear, but I will attempt an answer.

Routers route between networks, and routers have no idea what constitutes the public or private addressing. There in nothing inherent in IPv4 that distinguishes public or private addressing (which was somewhat arbitrarily defined). It is just that the ISPs agree not to route private addressing on the public Internet.

You can have a network that does not touch the public internet, and your router can still route between the networks attached to it. If you have a network with the DVR connected to one router interface, and you have other networks with various devices/PCs connected to other networks on other router interfaces, the router will happily route between the networks, absent any configuration, e.g. ACL, to block traffic between networks.

You can even create your own private internet that has multiple routers, each having multiple networks on multiple interfaces, and you can route between the networks. Routers don't really care how each device connects to the network at layer-1/2 (ethernet, Wi-Fi, token ring, etc.). In fact, a router will strip off the layer-2 frames and route the packets between the networks.

That means that you can have a wireless network and a wired network, and a router can route traffic between the networks.